# ElasticSearch NEST client difference between Text and TextPhrase

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

In looking at the documentation on text queries in the NEST documentation:
http://nest.azurewebsites.net/query/text.html

I'm unclear what the practical difference is between the Text and TextPhrase methods. My best guess is that both take into account the order of the words in the query, but that TextPhrase allows you to configure the importance of that order using the SLOP. Is that correct and the main difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Text` variety of queries were renamed to `Match` in Elasticsearch at some point (early 0.19 or 0.20 versions I believe).  You can find documentation for `Match` here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

The way they work is simple.  Given this phrase: "quick brown fox jumped", the `match` query is looking for:

- `quick` OR `brown` OR `fox` OR `jumped`

There is no ordering involved...`match` is simply looking for the presence of the individual tokens.  The token order could be completely random, distributed over an entire paragraph, and the document would come back as a result.

In contrast, the `match_phrase` is looking for:

- `"quick brown fox jumped"`

Because it is looking for phrases, the order of tokens matters.  With a default slop of zero, you have exact-phrase matching behavior.

If you increase the slop, you can make the phrase a little less precise.  For example, a slop of one allows a single edit to the phrase (an edit counts as an insertion, deletion or move of a word).  So a slop of one might also match any of these phrases:

- `"quick brown fox really jumped"`
- `"the quick brown fox jumped"`
- `"quick brown fox jumped high"`

It is important to know that slops do not maintain order either.  A slop of two allows two edits, so this phrase would also match:

- `"brown quick fox jumped"`

The first edit was moving "brown" to the first position, while the second edit was moving "quick" to the second position.  Since slop only cares about edit numbers, and not positioning, large slops tend to give you fairly confusing results.  A slop higher than 2-3 is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Its good to note that NEST also has `.Match()/.MatchPhrase()/.MatchPhrasePrefix()/.MultiMatch()` query constructs. The `Text*()` are kept around for backwards compatibility.